# How can white checkmate black in this chess puzzle?

Tags: chess

I was thinking about making some good chess puzzles and I found an interesting approach .

White to move.

[image: Puzzle[1]]

Assuming both players try to checkmate their opponent's kings , who will win the game?

Comment: Chess is also a boardgame and we welcome these questions here.

Comment: @DenisS Just because a question is on-topic for another stack doesn't mean that it isn't also valid here. Questions about chess are allowed here too.

Comment: My bad, retracted flag

Comment: If you want to make chess puzzles, a good place to start would be using images of actual chess boards and pieces... that image you had was very difficult to read as a chess board; especially since the squares were not all the same size. You can use this website to easily create your own game states to play around with and show: https://lichess.org/editor/RR4bk/1B1ppnp1/5PnP/2pN2P1/1b6/2P2pp1/1P1P1p2/7K_w_-_-_0_1

Comment: That was a very generous edit, @GendoIkari!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming white is moving up the board in the position as shown,

1.Rxg8+ Kh7
2.Rxg7#

BTW, the usual notation for Knight is N, not H.

You can also use online tools to make better pictures (and to produce more easily-shareable notation for the board).

For example https://www.365chess.com/analysis_board.php

For instance, your puzzle in FEN is

`RR4bk/1B1ppnp1/5PnP/2pN2P1/1b6/2P2pp1/1P1P1p2/7K w - - 0 1`

Comment: ok thanks for the information , and nice that you got the checkmate position

Comment: No need to assume. a1 is in the bottom left - white starts at a.

Comment: @HaroldEd  See the original unedited post for the ambiguity.